# Laravel - Get array with relationship

Tags: laravel

I have an ajax call that returns an array:

```
$reports = Report::where('submission_id', $submissionID)
    ->where('status', 'pending')
    ->get(['description','rule']);
    
return [
    'message' => 'Success.',
    'reports' => $reports,
];
```

From this array, I only want to return the fields 'description' and 'rule'. However I also want to return the `owner()` relationship from the `Report` model. How could I do this? Do I have to load the relationship and do some kind of array push, or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Use this `Report::where('submission_id', $submissionID) ->where('status', 'pending')->select('description', 'rule')->get();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up going with:

```
        $reports = Report::
            with(['owner' => function($q)
            {
                $q->select('username', 'id');
            }])         
            ->where('submission_id', $submissionID)
            ->where('status', 'pending')
            ->select('description', 'rule','created_by')
            ->get();
```

The other answers were right, I needed to load in the ID of the user. But I had to use a function for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with()` to eager load related model

```
$reports = Report::with('owner')
    ->where('submission_id', $submissionID)
    ->where('status', 'pending')
    ->get(['id','description','rule']);
```

Note you need to include `id` in `get()` from report model to map (owner) related model

Comment: This returns:       #relations: array:1 [
        "owner" => null
      ]

Answer (score 0):

you will have probably **one to many** relationship with **Reports** and **owners** table like below

**Report Model**

```
public function owner() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Owner');
}
```

**Owner Model**

```
public function reports() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Report');
}
```

**your controller code**

```
$reports = Report::with('owner')->
where('submission_id', $submissionID)->where('status', 'pending')->get()

return [
'message' => 'Success.',
'reports' => $reports,
```

];

Comment: This returns:       #relations: array:1 [
        "owner" => null
      ]

Comment: it's created_by in the reports table. The relationship looks like this: " return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class, 'created_by');". The relationship works just fine if I do a regular ->get() without the select.

Comment: then you can remove the select and only show the columns in the ajax result which you need.